# PHP 7.1 - Error

Tags: php, apache, pdo

I try to connect to the database with PDO, but I skip the exception:

```
Error: could not find driver
```

I'm using php 7.1 and Apache 2.4

I have uncommented the line extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll. Then restart the server but the same error keeps coming up.

php -m

```
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check with phpinfo(); to make sure you modified the right php.ini (Loaded Configuration File). Ususally CLI use a  different one. Check if you have pdo_mysql there too.

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer or XAMPP or did you install Apache and PHP manually?

Comment: I'm using linux and I install everything manually. Install apache

Comment: Then it seems a little strange that your extension is `extension = php_pdo_mysql.dll` as linux does not know what a `.dll` is